# How can I save/load the checked state of a Menu Item in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a Menu in an Electron application, and the items look something like this:

```
 const menuTemplate = [
    // ... previous menu items
    {
      label: "Notifications",
      submenu: [
        {
          label: "Enable reset notification",
          type: "checkbox",
          checked: true,
          click: e => {
            mainWindow.showResetNotification = e.checked;
          }
        },
        {
          label: "Reminder notifications",
          submenu: [
            {
              label: "Never",
              type: "radio",
              click: e => {
                if (e.checked) {
                  mainWindow.resetNotification = "never";
                }
              }
            },
            {
              label: "Every 30 minutes",
              type: "radio",
              click: e => { /* ... */ }
            },
            {
              label: "Every hour",
              type: "radio",
              checked: true,
              click: e => { /* ... */ }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to be able to check something, and save that state so that if I re-open the application, it loads the previous state of the checked menu item (checked vs unchecked).

How can I do this in Electron? I tried local storage, but because it's the main process, it doesn't have access to that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use `lowdb` in my project.Read some configuration files when the process starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a package like electron-store

It's less than <100 lines of code and only has a few dependencies.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store

Comment: This does the storage perfectly, thank you! I'll mark it as correct. Something is weird on the electron side (the proper values are stored but it's not checking the menu items), but that might be something I'm missing.